# DependencyService.Get<InterfaceImplemetation>() returns null

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have implemented a DependencyService for changing the Orientation of the Device for a specific Page.

ScreenRotation.cs

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(WhaleEstimate.Droid.ScreenRotation))]
        namespace WhaleEstimate.Droid
        {
            class ScreenRotation : IScreenRotation
            {
                public void DisableScreenRotation()
                {
                    Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
                }

                public void EnableScreenRotation()
                {
                    Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.FullSensor;
                }
            }
        }
```

Code in PCL:

```
private IScreenRotation screenRotationService;
screenRotationService = DependencyService.Get<IScreenRotation>();
if (screenRotationService != null)
{
     screenRotationService.EnableScreenRotation();
}
```

When executing, it reaches the Code-Snippet within the if-clause. Then the NullReferenceException is thrown. I have absoloutely no idea, why it reaches the Code-snippet within the if-clause and why the object is null.

**EDIT**

Exception Information:
[image]

Comment: have you tried using try catch to see what is the problem?

Comment: For which Information are you looking for?

Comment: encapsulate the screenRotationService.EnableScreenRotation(); inside the trycatch, and put a breakpoint inside the catch and see what the exception gives you

Comment: I'll attach the Output which is given to me to the Question. I can't see any Information that helps me

Comment: you can see clearly what is the problem then, see takeda anwser, you forgot to register the dependency service

Comment: If it goes into the if statement, then clearly the dependency managed to initialize. Can you put a breakpoint inside the EnableScreenRotation to see if it goes there? Maybe your CurrentActivity is null?

Comment: instead of using Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait; could you try this: var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

Comment: @MihailDuchev I also thought this, but the Breakpoints in the EnableScreenRotation() have no effect. The Application doesnt break and directly runs into the Exception. Is there maybe a reason, why the CurrentActivity could be null? Maybe the Method EnableScreenRotation must be called later or earlier?

Comment: @DisDes i will add this as an awnser then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving `NullReferenceException` probably because `Android.Content` is null thus giving you the exception, try changing ScreenRotation to this so you get the Activity Context:

```
public class ScreenRotation : IScreenRotation
{
    public void DisableScreenRotation()
    {
        var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
        activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait; 
    }

    public void EnableScreenRotation()
    {
         var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
         activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullSensor; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have used CurrentActivity plugin and it's working for me.
I think you forgot to initialize plug in your Android project MainActivity.cs file

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Expander_Experimental");
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

Android

**ScreenRotation.cs**

```
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Xamarin.Forms;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TestMobileApp.Droid.ScreenRotation))]
namespace TestMobileApp.Droid
{
    public class ScreenRotation : IScreenRotation
    {
        public void DisableScreenRotation()
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        }

        public void EnableScreenRotation()
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.FullSensor;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First. Did you register the dependency service in Initialization?. On app.xaml.cs

```
DependencyService.Register<IService, Service>();
```

Also, try to make the class public

Comment: I can only do this:   DependencyService.Register<IScreenRotation>();
and not             DependencyService.Register<IScreenRotation, ScreenRotation>();

Comment: Because i cant access the platformspecific implementation in PCL

Comment: Can you try register in the main activity before the loading of forms?

Comment: Try to change the implementation of your service to another thing. Like a test code. See if the problem it's the lack o the registration or the code itself

Comment: Also, Have you changed the implementation class to public? Maybe that why you couldn't access in the app.xaml.cs

Comment: just saying, you probably don't have ScreenRotation because the class is not public

Comment: I changed it, but i still cant Access it from app.xaml.cs

Comment: Is the Constructor of App.xaml.cs the Right place to Register? I placed it after InitializeComponent()

Comment: No, it is not. You don't need to register all of your services in App.xaml.cs!

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with "in my project"? The implementation is in the ANdroid Project and the Interface in the PCL

Comment: If you register the platform implementation by method, the code should be added in MainActivity class. Check the code: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/DependencyService/DependencyServiceDemos.Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: He's not registering it in the platform. He has added the Dependency attribute, as you can see, so there is no need of this.
`[assembly: Dependency(typeof(WhaleEstimate.Droid.ScreenRotation))]`